# SetRequiredLevel How it works?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, required

I have two fields : Cobertura and other 3 (lets call it x,y,z) If cobertura value is 150 or 160 I need to make the other 3 fields required and not allowed to save before fill these field, using java script in CRM 11. 
Using set required level will work for me? What exactly this function does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `setRequiredLevel` function will work in your case. The function changes the requirement level of the field (possible values are `none`, `recommended`, `required`)

you need to check the Cobertura value inside `OnLoad` and `OnChange` event:

```
var cobertura = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cobertura").getValue();
if (cobertura == 150 || cobertura == 160) {
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("x").setRequiredLevel("required");
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("y").setRequiredLevel("required");
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("z").setRequiredLevel("required");
} else {
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("x").setRequiredLevel("none");
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("y").setRequiredLevel("none");
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("z").setRequiredLevel("none");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially the same as Guido's just refactored

```
  function coberturaSetRequired()
     {

        var cobertura = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cobertura");
        var x = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("x");
        var y = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("y");
        var z = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("z");
        var isRequired = "none";

        if (!cobertura) return;

          if (cobertura.getValue() == 150 || cobertura.getValue() == 160)
          {
            isRequired = "required";
          }



        x.setRequiredLevel(isRequired);
        y.setRequiredLevel(isRequired);
        z.setRequiredLevel(isRequired);

    }
```

Comment: Copying someone else's answer and refactoring it is not enough for a good answer. Why is your answer better then Guido's?

Comment: Its not better, just how I would have wrote it, has more English language in it so could be easier to understand but will do the same job, i tried voting Guido's answer up but couldn't

Comment: you can edit my answer's code instead refactoring and post it as answer

Comment: You need more reputation to vote (or comment). One remark on `isRequired`: `isRequired` suggests the variables acts like a boolean, which is not the case. `if(isRequired){ ...}` won't have the desired/expected effect. I'll give you an upvote for trying to improve an answer.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't realize you could edit other peoples code like that, i will do that in the future thanks! yeah perhaps required would of been a better name thanks.

Comment: A full refactor should include the check if a field is in the form: `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cobertura") != undefined` and `isRequired` initialized in none so you don't have to use the else.

Answer (score 0):

Function `setRequiredLevel("required")` makes the data attribute *required*. The label of every control field on the web form displaying the attribute will get an asterisk (*) appended to the label text. The user will not be able to save the data on the form as long as the attribute remains empty.